# NSMutableDictionary order different in iOS8 (reversed from iOS7)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

For the last couple of years (pre iOS8/XCode 6) this code has produced a table in the order of

- Appliance Name
- Combustion gas analysis
- Safety checks
- Appliance checks
- Findings and Completion

now in iOS8/XCode 6 flips the order of the two NSMutableArray in the NSMutableDictionary, so it outputs

- Combustion gas analysis
- Safety checks
- Appliance checks
- Findings and Completion
- Appliance Name

Why???

```
#import "svServiceVC.h"
#import "SingletonID.h"
#import "escgasDatabase.h"
#import "FMDBDataAccess.h"

@interface svServiceVC ()
@end

@implementation svServiceVC

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.theTable.delegate = self;
    self.theTable.dataSource =self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self buildTableData];
    [_theTable reloadData];
}

- (void)buildTableData
{
    anApplianceNamed = 0;
    generalInspectationDone = 0;
    _appliancesDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [_appliancesDict setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"Appliances"];
    [_appliancesDict setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"Inspection"];

    // snip


    [[_appliancesDict objectForKey:@"Appliances"] addObject:appString1];

    [[_appliancesDict objectForKey:@"Inspection"] addObject:@"Combustion gas analysis"];

    [[_appliancesDict objectForKey:@"Inspection"] addObject:@"Safety checks"];

    [[_appliancesDict objectForKey:@"Inspection"] addObject:@"Appliance checks"];

    [[_appliancesDict objectForKey:@"Inspection"] addObject:@"Findings & Completion"];

    generalInspectationDone = 1;
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [_appliancesDict count];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[_appliancesDict valueForKey:[[_appliancesDict allKeys] objectAtIndex:section]] count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"AppCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell;
    NSArray *versionCompatibility = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    if ( 6 <= [[versionCompatibility objectAtIndex:0] intValue] )
    {
        // iOS6 is installed
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else
    {
        // iOS5 is installed
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
    }


    NSString *appTitle = [[_appliancesDict valueForKey:[[_appliancesDict allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = appTitle;

    if (indexPath.section==0)
    {
        // The appliance cells

        if ([cell.textLabel.text hasPrefix:@"Appliance"])
        {
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }



    }
    else
    {

        // The inspection rows

        if (indexPath.row==0)
        {
            //
            if (gasInspection==0)
            {
                cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            }
            else
            {
                cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            }


        }
        else if (indexPath.row==1)
        {
            // * Gas inpsection

            if (safetyChecks==0)
            {
                cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            }
            else
            {
                cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            }


        }
        else if (indexPath.row==2)
        {
            // * Gas inpsection

            if (applianceChecks==0)
            {
                cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            }
            else
            {
                cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            }


        }
        else if (indexPath.row==3)
        {

            if (generalInspectationDone==0)
            {
                //cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
                cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            }
            else
            {
                cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            }

        }


    }

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexpath %li %li",(long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row);

    switch (indexPath.section)
    {
        case 0:

            // Appliances
            [SingletonID sharedSingleton].appliance = @"_1";


            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"svApplianceSegue" sender:self];
            break;

        case 1:


            switch (indexPath.row){

            case 0:
                [self goGasAnalysis];
                break;

            case 1:
                [self goSafety];
                break;

            case 2:
                [self goChecks];
                break;

            case 3:
                [self goComplete];
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: It must be an implementation change in dictionary, but it always was and still is an inherently unordered collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSString *appTitle = [[_appliancesDict valueForKey:[[_appliancesDict allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

You are using `allKeys` to get the list of 'sections', in this case "Appliances" and "Inspections". The problem here is that a Dictionary does not enforce an ordering of its keys. You can see this in the documentation for [NSDictionary's allKeys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/allKeys), as it explicitly states this fact.

> `allKeys`
>
> *Returns a new array containing the dictionary’s keys.*
>
> **Return Value**:  A new array containing the dictionary’s keys, or an empty array if the dictionary has no entries.
>
> **Discussion**: The order of the elements in the array is not defined.

It seems something changed in the implementation of NSDictionary in iOS 8 that has affected the internal ordering of keys. Because the API never guaranteed a fixed ordering in the first place, Apple are fine to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries are unordered.  This is *an implementation detail*.  The answer to "Why?" is that Apple changed the implementation.  Since they know that good code would never depend on the order, they are free to do so.

If you want to have your keys in a specific order, you could keep a separate array with your keys stored in the order you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says:

> allKeys Returns a new array containing the dictionary’s keys.
>
> -(NSArray *)allKeys
>
> Return Value
>
> A new array containing the dictionary’s keys, or an empty array if the dictionary has no entries.
>
> Discussion
>
> **The order of the elements in the array is not defined.**

(emphasis added)

So NSDictionary is permitted to return the keys in any order. Technically it can randomise the order every single time you call `allKeys` and still hit its contractual obligations.

There need be no specific reason why the order changes. Use `-keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:` (or by comparator), or sort the `allKeys` array yourself if you want a deterministic ordering.